# Why is HMAC-SHA512 used on root the root seed to create master private key and chain code in HD wallets?

Tags: private-key, hash, bip32-hd-wallets

The process is depicted in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/develop/images/mbc2_0509.png) picture. Specifically, given that the root seed was derived using PBKDF2 (with 2048 rounds of hashing with HMAC-SHA256 already), why do we undergo an additional pass of HMAC-SHA512, besides for creating 512 bits of entropy? Why not just use SHA512 alone? I've asked here before and the answer I got was that the HMAC version is used to ensure unique generation of the key, but I don't know what that means. It seems for derivation of the master private key and chain node, the function is being used as a one-way hash function only, so why is a MAC being used? There is a single thing being encrypted, we are not additionally trying to guarantee authenticity on anything here, right?

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically, given that the root seed was derived using PBKDF2 (with 2048 rounds of hashing with HMAC-SHA256 already), why do we undergo

and

> an additional pass of HMAC-SHA512, besides for creating 512 bits of entropy?

Those things come from different standards. BIP32 (which specifies going from masterkey to keys) came first. Various ways for constructing master keys/seeds are in use that came later; I assume you're referring to one of those.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not just use SHA512 alone?

I'm not sure. I think that would work fine. The only tricky detail would be that you need include the passphrase, too.

> It seems for derivation of the master private key and chain node, the function is being used as a one-way hash function only,

To be entirely accurate, you need more than a one-way function. For example, if the hash function always produced a hash that was divisible by 3, that would follow [all of the properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the hash function, but it would be weaker as a key derivation function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet the 2048 rounds of hashing required by the BIP 39 Standard takes considerably more energy than 1 round of hashing.

Put another way, substantial computing cycles are required to create brute forced **Rainbow Tables** when lower entropy human readable seeds are functionally mapped to private keys. This is somewhat analogous to the leading hash zeroes values miners satisfy to add blocks to a PoW-based blockchain, except the computing cylces are fixed by [**mnemonics-to-seed**](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#from-mnemonic-to-seed) portion of the BIP39 Standard.

The Python [**stretch**](https://pypi.org/project/stretch/) can effectively implement the mnemonics-to-seed functionality written into BIP 39.

`stretch->passlib.pbkdf2(secret, “mnemonic”+salt, rounds=2048, keylength=64, sha512)`

The two two Bitcoin-related examples of piped commands using **stretch** and [**bx**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki#about-bitcoin-explorer) yield the same result.

**% stretch -f sha512 -r 2048 "bunker wreck real edge inflict aerobic buddy mercy divorce wolf bright immune fat foot poet section sustain reveal unique reflect have latin problem chapter" mnemonic123 | bx base64-decode | bx base16-encode | bx hd-new | bx hd-private**
`xprv9veSXAfA7GoYvaMAXgm3uYGS4VLH1Foc9qmTBRCb4c3F2Vqd261k2vo646nLU54MRVseFx2BbhZYQS9HDUy4dvTV3fygVGxedqYSR82B3he`

**% echo "bunker wreck real edge inflict aerobic buddy mercy divorce wolf bright immune fat foot poet section sustain reveal unique reflect have latin problem chapter" | bx mnemonic-to-seed -p 123 | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private**
`xprv9veSXAfA7GoYvaMAXgm3uYGS4VLH1Foc9qmTBRCb4c3F2Vqd261k2vo646nLU54MRVseFx2BbhZYQS9HDUy4dvTV3fygVGxedqYSR82B3he`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why HMAC-SHA-512 is used as opposed to SHA-512.

Comment: Rainbow tables aren't applicable to BIP39; the key space is too large to construct them.

Comment: % echo -n "Bull Shit" | bx base16-encode | bx sha256 | bx mnemonic-new
`shiver enact raise shoe vocal evidence dismiss lawsuit hospital multiply project wonder art fish next club bridge steak ritual face recipe school knife second`